# How to insert into TABLE1 (field1,field2 'value','myval','currentdate') select(field1,field2) from TABLE2

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I want to insert value from `TABLE2` (2 field) into another `TABLE1` (containing 5 field).

When I execute query:

```
insert into TABLE1  select (field1, field2) from TABLE2
```

My rest three fields became *null*.

I want to insert my new value like current date and new id in `TABLE1`.

How to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS

```
insert into TABLE1 (field1,field2 'value','myval','currentdate') select field1,field2,'your value','other value',NOW() from TABLE2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify new columns next to `field1` and `field2`.

If you are using MS Sql Server, for example:

```
Insert into table1

Select row_number() over(order by field1) as newID, field1, field2, Getdate(), value3

From table2
```

Comment: Thanks.. But I have insert different different type of value. Actually my field is organization_ID and current_date, I can add current_date But organization_ID is not fixed, it comes dynamically and saved in variable name $org_id.. Thanks again in advance